# Memory Leaks in main.m while profiling in Instruments?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks

In my one of the app i am getting memory leak in UIKit,UIFoundation and QuartzCore. When i go for call tree it showing leak in `main.m`. I really didn't have any clue why is this happening. You can see the screen shots of the memory leak below.[image]

**In Call Tree**

[image]

**How to resolve this leaks?**

**MEMORY LEAK CODE**

```
- (void) showCustomPrices
{

int priceValue = 0;
NSArray* priceSplitValue = [btnpriceButton.titleLabel.text componentsSeparatedByString: @"."];
NSString* priceFinal = [priceSplitValue objectAtIndex:0];

for(int i=0;i<[priceArray count];i++)
{ 
    if([[priceArray objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:priceFinal]){
        priceValue = i; 
    }
}


    //Assign the cocktail to picker view
    priceActionsheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                              delegate:self
                                     cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];//as we want to display a subview we won't be using the default buttons but rather we're need to create a toolbar to display the buttons on

    [priceActionsheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];

    CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0);

    pricePickerview = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
    pricePickerview.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    pricePickerview.dataSource = self;
    pricePickerview.delegate = self;


    [priceActionsheet addSubview:pricePickerview];
    //[pickerView release];

    priceToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 485, 44)];
    priceToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    [priceToolbar sizeToFit];

    NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
    [barItems addObject:flexSpace];

    UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneButtonPressed:)];
    [barItems addObject:doneBtn];

    UIBarButtonItem *cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancelButtonPressed:)];
    [barItems addObject:cancelBtn];

    [pricePickerview selectRow:priceValue inComponent:0 animated:YES];//Memory leaks shows 100% here

    [priceToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];

    [priceActionsheet addSubview:priceToolbar];

    [priceActionsheet addSubview:pricePickerview];

    [priceActionsheet showInView:self.view];  

    [priceActionsheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 485, 320)];
```

}

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you click the small arrow beside the object's address in the first diagram it will show you the retain/release history.  I find that the best clue about what's holding on to the object.

Comment: @PhillipMills Edited my question please have a look at it. thanks

Comment: In the top bar there are 3 'View' Buttons. select also the right most one to see the stack trace and see if there is a method call from you app code.

Comment: @OrArbel i can see the stack trace but couldn't find any method call from the app code..Updated my question please have a look at it

Comment: have you made property for the UIPickerView? Is the reference strong?

Comment: @abdullahUmer Yes i declared and its strong

Comment: why not try using the property? like use self.pricePickerview and see what happens.

Comment: @AbdullahUmer Thanks for your comment. Finally i solved the problem please see my answer below for explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i solved my problem by moving the picker view `allocation/initialisation`part from the method `showCustomePrices` to `viewwillAppear`. Which works awesome without any memory leaks.

What is happened before is whenever i click the button it popups the `pickerview` with memory allocation. Thats why the memory leak is happened.

Now after moving in to `viewwillAppear` it just allocating on first time when the view gets loaded. Then Picker View is accessed without any memory allocation. So memory leaks is removed.

Comment: Thats weird. I have used UIPickerView in my project and I'm allocating+init whenever a UIButton is pushed. But I don't have the leak.

Comment: Yeah its really wired. I have used the same in different project it worked but not in this

Comment: and if one time allocation is working for you, I think its better to have it in viewDidLoad() instead of viewWillAppear().

Comment: yes i can but as per my project requirements i am changing the array of the pickerview whenever there is change in settings. So its working perfectly in viewwillappear than viewdidload

Answer (score 1):

If your project is non-ARC, it may be because you have left `[super dealloc];` somewhere subclassing foundation classes. I had the same issue with a subclass of `NSObject`. I had forgot to write `[super dealloc];` and was getting some what similar leaks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer..I created project in ARC and some copied from non-ARC project. I am not sure how to approach your answer

Comment: are you sure there aren't any leaks in the non-ARC part of the project?

Comment: I hope so but how to check that specifically?

Comment: i have one static table view controller which is groped. I commented the `cellforrowatindexpath` because it doesn't need for static. but the leak look pointing to this method.

Comment: I really dont remember now. It was a year ago. I was almost convinced like you that the leak is from Foundation libraries and I ignored it. But after a couple of days when I was going through my old codes, I saw a class without [super dealloc]; :/ and Bingo!...

Comment: updated my code which has memory leaks how to get rid of that thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
```

try this in your main.m

Answer (score -1):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, @"yourAppName", nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```