# Memory leaks in main method and in a block

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

I am finding the leaks in my application.I am using a plug in named SWRevealcontroller when i search for leaks using instruments i am getting leaks as shown in the screen shots.I am unable to resolve those leaks.

[image: leak in swrevealcontroller file]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Is there any way to fix these leaks.
I have followed certain tutorials but i am unable to resolve these issues.

[Memory Leaks in main.m while profiling in Instruments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13644655/memory-leaks-in-main-m-while-profiling-in-instruments)

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/instruments-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-debug-memory-leaks

- (void)prepareForSegue: (UIStoryboardSegue *) segue sender: (id) sender {

  if ( [segue isKindOfClass: [SWRevealViewControllerSegue class]] ) {

  ```
  SWRevealViewControllerSegue *swSegue = (SWRevealViewControllerSegue*) segue;
  ```

  swSegue.performBlock = ^(SWRevealViewControllerSegue* rvc_segue, UIViewController* svc, UIViewController* dvc)

  {

  ```
      UINavigationController* navController = (UINavigationController*)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;

      [navController setViewControllers: @[dvc] animated: NO ];

    NSLog(@"abcd %@",dvc);

     NSLog(@"abcde %@",segue);
      [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];

  };
  ```

  }

this is the point where i am using that block.

Comment: Add a link to these "certain tutorials".

Comment: yeah i have added them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done the modification told by user2260054 and i have added

__typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;

now its working fine.

Comment: According to this article thirdcog.eu/pwcblocks there are even more possible problems with memory management using blocks as well as even more solutions. Each block retains self, not only when you use self explicitly, but even if you use any instance variable inside of a block(and latter is an object)! Also not only __weak modifier can prevent problems (this prevents increasing self's retain counter), but also __block modifier if you din't use ARC mode(this also makes variable mutable inside of the block, which is not true by default). Be careful!

Answer (score 2):

Use copy for blocks as properties instead of strong and make sure you do not use self inside blocks. If you need it create weak copy of self.

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void(^performBlock)(...);

...
//if you need self inside of any block
id __weak weakSelf = self;
...^(){
   //use weakSelf instead of self;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion.I tried it but where ever i change(at 2 places)it is showing error as property not found on object of type'__weak id const'

Comment: What exactly you tried? Is it about weakSelf? By the way, it should be id __weak, not __weak id. And I used 'id' just as an example because I don't know what class are you using it inside.

Comment: __typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self; i tried this its working fine.May i know the reason what it should be weak inside the block.

Comment: You can read more about blocks in articles like this one http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/10/how-blocks-are-implemented-and.html. In short, that's because any block is an object and it retains any variable it uses. Since your __typeof(self) also retains the block this creates a retain cycle.

Comment: Thanks for that help.Will you please confirm the line of code that i have written is correct or wrong.

Comment: What do you mean? This one :__typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;?It looks good. Let me know if you still have memory leaks.